# Permission Set Metadata Missing Tab Visiblity?

Tags: metadata, metadata-api, eclipse

I'm trying to get some new permission sets that grant access to custom tabs into source control, but the resulting metadata doesn't contain any tab visibilities.  Is this a known hole in the metadata api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a version issue.  Per the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_permissionset.htm) tab visibilities are only available with api version 26 and later.  Was able to get the metadata with ant v25 as long as the package.xml version specified version 26.  Have not been able to figure out how to do this directly in Eclipse as it always overrides any changes to the package.xml version.